# How I get the real dimensions of an object that is using a particle system?

Tags: scripting

I'm rendering some grass using a particle system

And this is the dimensions of my plane with grass

[image]

If I disable the particle system the dimensions stay the same though the grass is no longer overflowing the edge

[image]

I'm making a script that needs to know the actual size of the object, including when the grass is present.

So far the only way I found how to get the dimensions of an object

```
for obj in bpy.context.view_layer.objects:
    obj.dimenstions.x # here I can get x,y,z
```

But this just gives me the same values I get in the normal UI view

Is it possible in blender to get the actual size when using a particle system?

Comment: You can save your file first to store your progress then press Convert to Mesh in the Modifiers panel to see the dimensions of the newly generated mesh object. Or you can export the particle system as alembic file and reimport it again. If you can explain more what is the purpose of the script there may be other solutions to your final goal?

Comment: In the end I just hardcoded a padding

Comment: For a particle system I would have had no idea apart from converting to mesh, if you made this with _Geometry Nodes_ you could use a _Realize Instances_ node and plug it into a _Bounding Box_ node. Even if you do not want to show the bounding box and do not use the realized instances on the output, you can use a _Vector Math_ node and subtract _Max_ - _Min_ and store the result as an attribute.